# Set UpdateTargetId dynamically or change UpdateTargetId

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view where i am using the:-

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Files", new AjaxOptions
{
HttpMethod = "POST",
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
UpdateTargetId = "divFile-" + Model.FileId,
OnSuccess = "editPrivilegeLevelForFileSuccess",
OnFailure = "editPrivilegeLevelForFileFailure"
}))
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FileId)
```

The problem here is the UpdateTargetId:-

My model currently doesnot have FileId value.
I am setting the value of Hidden field by jquery method and it works well.

```
$("#FileId").val(fileId);
```

But how can I set the same value in UpdateTargetId?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value of this property is known only on the client side you could do that inside the OnSuccess callback. So get rid of the `UpdateTargetId` property from your AjaxOptions and then inside the `editPrivilegeLevelForFileSuccess` handler you could manually update the corresponding section:

```
function editPrivilegeLevelForFileSuccess(result) {
    var fileId = $('#FileId').val();
    $('#divFile-' + fileId).html(result);
}
```

Comment: Awesome man.....You are just genious. :).
I was scratching my head from past 3 hours.
Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you look how a form tag is produced from Ajax.BeginForm:

```
<form id="form0" action="/Redirects/Manage/List" method="post" novalidate="novalidate" data-ajax-update="#page" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax="true">
```

You can use jquery to alter this, for example on OnChange event of a dropdown:

```
@Html.DropDownList("language", new SelectList(@Model.Locales, "Key", "Value"), new { onchange = "$(this.form).attr('data-ajax-update','#nowhere');$(this.form).submit();" }
```

Comment: The simplest solution. I also did the same :)